# Faulty base-case Haskell

Tags: haskell, design-patterns

My functions:

```
type Block = [Maybe Int] 

checkBlock' :: Block -> Block
checkBlock' (r:rs)
    | r == [] = []
    | isJust r == True = r:checkBlock' rs
    | isNothing r == True = checkBlock' rs

checkBlock :: Block -> Block
checkBlock (r:rs)
    | r == [] = []
    | isNothing r == True = r:checkBlock rs
    | isJust r == True    = checkBlock rs
```

I want to first function to inspect a list of Just Ints and Nothings, and return only the Just values. And the second function to return only the Nothings.

They compile fine without the basecase where `r == [] = []`, but with it i get the error:

```
Sudoku.hs:104:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Int' with actual type `[t0]'
    In the second argument of `(==)', namely `[]'
    In the expression: r == []
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for checkBlock':
      r == []
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What can I place there instead of [] to make this compile? I've run ut of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You should use pattern matching here, not guards:

```
checkBlock :: Block -> Block
checkBlock [] = []
checkBlock (r:rs)
    | isNothing r == True = r:checkBlock rs
    | isJust r == True    = checkBlock rs
```

or, preferably:

```
checkBlock :: Block -> Block
checkBlock [] = []
checkBlock (Nothing : rs) = Nothing : checkBlock rs
checkBlock (Just _ : rs) = checkBlock rs
```

Comment: @Rewbert Also note that `x == True` is the exact same as `x`.  You should just have `| isNothing r = r : checkBlock rs` and similarly for the next line.

Comment: `checkBlock = filter isNothing`

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `r` with empty list, you could compare the whole list only.

As an alternative, you could write

```
checkBlock :: Block -> Block
checkBlock rs
    | rs == [] = []
    | isNothing (head rs) == True = (head rs):checkBlock (tail rs)
    | isJust (head rs) == True    = checkBlock (tail rs)
```

Second, guards are already use `Bool`, so `== True` is unnecessary. by the way, try to use `null rs` istaed of `rs == []`

```
checkBlock :: Block -> Block
checkBlock rs
    | null rs              = []
    | isNothing (head rs)  = (head rs):checkBlock (tail rs)
    | isJust (head rs)     = checkBlock (tail rs)
```

But this looks a bit ugly, let's use pattern matching:

```
checkBlock :: Block -> Block
checkBlock [] = []
checkBlock (r:rs)
    | isNothing r  = r:checkBlock rs
    | isJust r     = checkBlock rs
```